# MySQL where between and multi or like

Tags: mysql, sql, date, where-clause, sql-like

Here is the example query:

```sql
select
    email,
    firstName,
    lastName
from
    users
where
    createdAt between '2020-04-01 00:00:00.0' and '2020-09-30 23:59:59.0'
    or email like '%bob%'
    or firstName like '%bob%'
    or lastName like '%bob%'
order by
    createdAt desc
```

The results I'm getting back are for example:

```
remi10@martin10.com,remi10,martin10
remi6@martin6.com,Bobby,martin6
remi5@gmail.com,Bob,martin5
remi4@gmail.com,remi4,martin4
```

I am trying to get ...

```
remi6@martin6.com,Bobby,martin6
remi5@gmail.com,Bob,martin5
```

It should be returning the records that have the `%bob%` between the provided date/time period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It should be returning the records that have the %bob% between the provided date/time period.

You need `and` between the date filter and the multiple like conditions. I would also recommend using half-open interval filtering to simplify the date filter:

```
where
    createdAt >= '2020-04-01' 
    and createdAt < '2020-10-01'
    and (
       email like '%bob%'
        or firstName like '%bob%'
        or lastName like '%bob%'
   )
```

Comment: Thanks, yes thats what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would suggest simplifying the data logic.  Second, you need parentheses:

```
where (createdAt >= '2020-04-01' and
       createdAt < '2020-10-01'
       ) and
       ( email like '%bob%' or
         firstName like '%bob%' or
         lastName like '%bob%' 
       )
```